# Getting SyntaxError from Coordinate Transformation (points) with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, coordinate-system, point, arcgis-pro, syntaxerror

I'm trying to do a coordinate transformation for points with ArcPy in ArcGIS Pro by using x and y coordinates as Input.

I tried the following:

```
import arcpy 
inputSRS = arcpy.SpatialReference(31467) 
outputSRS = arcpy.SpatialReference(25832)
gt = 'DHDN_To_ETRS_1989_3'
pt = arcpy.Point() 
pt.X = 3453122.083947168 
pt.Y = 5427803.663703325 
print "Input XY: {} {}".format(pt.X, pt.Y)
ptgeo = arcpy.PointGeometry(pt, inputSRS)
ptgeo1 = ptgeo.projectAs(outputSRS, gt)
pt1 = ptgeo1.lastPoint
print "Output XY: {} {}".format(pt1.X, pt1.Y)
```

I get a SyntaxError.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax error is not an arcpy error, it is a pure python error. ArcGIS Pro uses Python 3, and you need to add parentheses around the print function.

```
import arcpy 
inputSRS = arcpy.SpatialReference(31467) 
outputSRS = arcpy.SpatialReference(25832)
gt = 'DHDN_To_ETRS_1989_3'
pt = arcpy.Point() 
pt.X = 3453122.083947168 
pt.Y = 5427803.663703325 
print ("Input XY: {0} {1}".format(pt.X, pt.Y))
ptgeo = arcpy.PointGeometry(pt, inputSRS)
ptgeo1 = ptgeo.projectAs(outputSRS, gt)
pt1 = ptgeo1.lastPoint
print ("Output XY: {0} {1}".format(pt1.X, pt1.Y))
```

Here is the output:

```
Input XY: 3453122.083947168 5427803.663703325
Output XY: 453065.4793016275 5426072.203723424
```